# Web App for Containers (Linux) version of app_offline.htm

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

Occasionally, there are times when a system needs to undergo maintenance for a short time. Standard Web Apps handle this by redirecting all traffic to an `app_offline.htm` if the file exists in the root directory (`wwwroot`). What is the equivalent for a Linux Web App for Containers instance?

I tried using Kudu's Bash terminal by echoing the minimum html contents into an `app_offline.htm` but it isn't working.

One thing I was looking into would be having a specific container image that is for maintenance, but that doesn't seem very elegant.

Eventually, I would like to be able to automate this via Azure DevOps.

Comment: What do you want? Another service like Web App for Container? Or just need a solution to update your app without down time?

Comment: While maintenance is ongoing, I would like to be able to work with the staging slot to ensure the fixes are correct. This would require downtime (disaster recovery, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to create an app setting with the name SCM_CREATE_APP_OFFLINE and a value of 1 to see if this allows the creation of a app_offline.htm file?

Comment: I Added SCM_CREATE_APP_OFFLINE and checked on Kudu. The default existed and was set to 1, but the app_offline.htm file in wwwroot is still being ignored.

Comment: I can create the app_offline.htm through Kudu's bash portal, but the app is not reflecting that.